# Circuit analysis: how to find the voltage at node 2?

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

**Find the voltage at node 1, 2 and 3 using mesh analysis.**

[image]

Using mesh analysis I have 3 equations:
$$
6ia+10ib-4ic = 0
$$
$$
-2ia-2ib+4ic = 10
$$
$$
ia-ib=-5
$$

With this equation I find the current values and node voltages except for node 2.

- ia = -2.5A
- ib= 2.5A
- ic = 2.5A
  \$ ~\\\$
- v1 = -10v
- v2 = ?
- v3 = 20v

[image]

**Edit:** But with the wrong directions I can't seem to find v2 using v1 - v2 = 2ix ; -10 - v2 = -10 , I only get v2 = 0

*Red marker in image:* Adding sign convention at the current source and unknown voltage variable. I don't know if this is okay to do so feel free to criticize.

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong with your solution. If V3 = 30V then V1 needs to be +10V. It can't be -10V.

Comment: i assume a wrong direction of current 4(-ia) = -10V, should i really change it to positive? will it not mess up the equations? and also v3 is 20V

Comment: Hard to tell, because you did not designate the resistors and the currents. So, your equations are unreadable for me.

Comment: @Newstudent I agree with G36. I can't make sense of your loop equations.

Comment: This should be https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqmMs.png

Comment: i just did clockwise meshes and the two 2 ohms currents goes right.

Comment: @Antonio51 from the image it seems i can use ewaution V2 - V1 = Vr1 or V2 - V3 = Vr2 to find V2,

Comment: this is what i work https://i.imgur.com/1lZQQDV.png

Comment: New student, you have enough posts now that I'd like to point out that 1) you don't need to use all-caps, 2) you don't need to use bold so much, and 3) the pronoun "I" should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your diagram from comments:

[image]

I've added labels you should have added. You should get in the practice of always solving symbolically and not using specific numbers. It's much better practice.

And just use \$v_2\$ as the unknown voltage across \$I_z\$ for two of the loops:

Starting at the lower-left corner of each loop and following your arrows:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}-R_1\cdot i_a-R_2\cdot\left(i_a-i_c\right)-v_2&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}+v_2-R_3\cdot\left(i_b-i_c\right)-R_4\cdot i_b&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}+v_z-R_3\cdot\left(i_c-i_b\right)-R_2\cdot\left(i_c-i_a\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

You also know (and need) one more fact, which I think you already identified: \$i_z=i_b-i_a\$.

So these make up four equations and four unknowns (I'm using freely available [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) for this -- they run on a variety of environments and use the [Python](https://www.python.org/) language):

```
from sympy import *                        # required once per session
from sympy.solvers import solve            # required once per session
var( 'ia ib ic iz vz r1 r2 r3 r4 v2')             # declare variables
eqa = Eq( 0 - r1*ia - r2*(ia-ic) - v2, 0 )        # loop ia
eqb = Eq( 0 + v2 - r3*(ib-ic) - r4*ib, 0 )        # loop ib
eqc = Eq( 0 + vz - r3*(ic-ib) - r2*(ic-ia), 0 )   # loop ic
eqiz = Eq( iz, ib - ia )                          # iz related to ia and ib
results = solve( [ eqa, eqb, eqc, eqiz ], [ ia, ib, ic, v2 ] )
results
{ia: (-iz*r4 + vz)/(r1 + r4),
 ib: (iz*r1 + vz)/(r1 + r4),
 ic: (iz*r1*r3 - iz*r2*r4 + r1*vz + r2*vz + r3*vz + r4*vz)/(r1*r2 + r1*r3 + r2*r4 + r3*r4),
 v2: (iz*r1*r2*r3 + iz*r1*r2*r4 + iz*r1*r3*r4 + iz*r2*r3*r4 - r1*r3*vz + r2*r4*vz)/(r1*r2 + r1*r3 + r2*r4 + r3*r4)}
for i in results: i, results[i].subs( { r1:4, r2:2, r3:2, r4:8, iz:5, vz:10 } )
(ia, -5/2)
(ib, 5/2)
(ic, 5/2)
(v2, 20)
```

Note that \$v_2\$ just falls out for you. Your computed loop currents are correct, as shown above.

Looking at your diagram, you already seem to have noticed that the net current through \$R_3\$ (now you see why you want to label all the parts!) is \$0\:\text{A}\$. If the current through a resistor is zero then the voltage drop across that resistor is also zero. So it must follow that \$v_3=20\:\text{V}\$, as well. Or, reversing that logic as you already worked out that \$v_3=20\:\text{V}\$, then it must be the case that \$v_2=20\:\text{V}\$, too.

Looks like you did fine. Just missed that small point. You are doing pretty well. Keep up the good work!

---

Per your comment below:

> How do you identify the sign of V2 across 5A during a loop? is there a
> sign convention?

It doesn't matter. Let's strip things down to the current source itself and examine that part of the diagram again:

[image]

It just turns out that there was a convenient node, \$v_2\$, which I used. But there is an ***implied*** reference for \$v_2\$, which is ground. So \$v_2=v_b\$ in the above diagram. The only difference here is that I've made the polarity ***explicit*** with \$v_b\$ where with \$v_2\$ it is ***implicit***.

I could have used \$v_b\$ interchangeably with \$v_2\$ and I would have gotten the same result.

Now, your question asks me (in effect), *"What would happen if you used \$v_a\$, instead?"*

In this case, I would have changed the signs I used in the first two equations shown above (because the polarity is oppositely arranged.) Then the solution would have been \$v_a=-20\:\text{V}\$. But as you can see, all this would mean is that the (+) terminal of \$v_a\$ is \$-20\:\text{V}\$. But this is ground. So that means the (-) terminal of \$v_a\$ would be \$-\left(-20\right)=+20\:\text{V}\$. So the result is exactly the same for \$v_2=-v_a=v_b\$.

The *convention* matters ***only*** in the sense that you apply it, consistently. You make a choice and then interpret it, accordingly. The meaning of the answers will be the same, regardless. But meaning is in your head. Different equation formulations can give you different numbers -- math doesn't care. But the meaning of those numbers comes from how you interpret them. And if you interpret them correctly you will get the same meaning out of them, regardless of the signs of the numbers that the mathematics provides you.

Think of this another way. ***Sound reasoning*** is the combination of ***valid logic*** applied to ***true assumptions***. You must have true assumptions, or else even valid logic produces garbage. You must have applied valid logic, or else even true assumptions produce garbage. Both are required to get ***sound results***. When you choose a polarity for a voltage difference (and it doesn't matter which way you choose), the only requirement is that you maintain its ***truth***, while you then apply valid logic/mathematics to it. If you alter the meaning half-way through your application of logic, you have invalidated your true assumption and it's no longer true. But if you keep true to your starting assumptions and apply consistent, valid logic to your work, the results will be sound. The only thing left to it is your interpretation of those results. But the soundly reasoned results will still be soundly reasoned. It's just in your head what they mean to you.

Comment: Can you share what the code block is from? Is that Mathematica or Matlab or something?

Comment: @JakeNixon Added a line in the answer to help there.

Comment: @JakeNixon I try to only use freely available and open software for anything I do in answers here. I want others able to replicate my results on their own without paying money or having to disclose personal information to do so.

Comment: @periblepsis How do you identify the sign of V2 across 5A during a loop? is there a sign convention? and i never knew you could do that.

Comment: @Newstudent It does not matter. You pick one and stick with it. Feel free to choose the opposite I chose. If you chose the opposite polarity and get -20 for the difference across the 5 A source, all that means is that the node voltage is still +20 with respect to ground because you must recognize the polarity you chose.

Comment: @Newstudent I'll write a short note in the answer, since this seems to be confusing.